# IDE's Java runtime (1.8u111) is outdated - this may cause stability issues. Please update to 1.8.0u112 or newer while opening PhpStorm in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: phpstorm

I recently updated PhpStorm to latest version 2017.1 and I get following message while starting PhpStorm

> IDE's Java runtime (1.8u111) is outdated - this may cause stability
>   issues. Please update to 1.8.0u112 or newer

Comment: Why not do what it says. Update the Java runtime. Your new update needs it for stability.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

But If you don't have the latest JDK, download it from: 
[Download latest JAVA JDK here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

And then select the "IDE BOOT JDK" like Tall Liou told.

Answer (score 19):

Start the IDE, use Help | Find Action (Ctrl+Shift+A or Cmd+Shift+A on Mac), type "Switch IDE Boot JDK", press Enter.

Comment: Just a comment on the lack of consistency in terminology. The warning talks about the "IDE's Java runtime", but the action is about the "IDE Boot JDK." They don't make it easy for you to find the settings/action option. :^(